# Import OpenStreetMap in to Neo4j with certain structure

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap

How can I import a .osm (OpenStreetMap) file into Neo4j,
so that I have a label *Street* for **addr:street**, with Property *housenumber* of **addr:housenumber**.

I also want to have a label *Postcode* of **addr:postcode**, and of couse relationship between nodes.

Is that structure possible with Neo4j spatial? Or does a alternative exist?
How can I do that, I have Neo4j COMMUNITY EDITION 3.0.4.

**Edit:**
I managed to import the OSM data in to Neo4j (by using maxdemarzi/OSM class in Netbeans), but I see now at Database Information:

- Node labels: only ReferenceNode.
- Relationship types: BBOX, Changeset, .. Ways
- Property keys: addr:city, addr:country, addr:housenumber .. zone

How can I make my own structure?

Comment: What did you try to import the data?

Comment: I looked at some code snippets, for instance: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/OSM/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amhg/TestOsm.java

And this guide: https://shapingknowledge.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/neo4j-spatial-introduction-and-installation/

But I am still uncertain about what kind of structure I will get, how will the data be connected and will that be the way I expect it to be.